# How to name invocable classes?

Tags: webservices, invocable-method

By design, a class can only have one invocable method - which is very different from the way you could design classes containing web service methods (where you could have multiple exposed methods). For me, this begs the question - how do you even name those classes in a good way? Surely for singletons that are so highly specialized, there should be some way to distinguish them from normal classes? But so far I've only come across orgs that do this in various different ways and it really doesn't help with understanding the codebase.

Right now I tend to prefix the classes with `Invocable` (or suffix them with something like `Action`) together with a shorter version of the method name in the class. But I'm not sure if this is really a good way - I just notice that I still struggle to keep track of all the invocable classes in an org. Any advice on this?

Edit:
I do think that using the flow builder to see which invocable methods you have (unhelpfully grouped by category) does not really work well from a dev perspective. A custom folder structure might improve things but it's still a pain to work with in the Salesforce org itself (if you ever need to). And it still requires you to create a separate package for those classes which is not feasible at all if you're already working with different packages.

I guess the question boils a little bit down to: "How to name these special singletons?"

And if you want to do that at all is - once again - subjective.

Comment: We do something similar, using a suffix "Invocable", but using a prefix would group all these classes together. To "track the invocables", just open the flow builder and try inserting an Action, filter by Type, select Apex Action then click in the selector - this presents the list of invocable methods you have. Or simply search across your code base for "@InvocableMethod".

Comment: BTW, I voted to close since this is, fundamentally, an opinion-based question (IMHO).

Comment: I do understand that it's somewhat opinionated, but the problem is that this addresses an (IMHO) shortcoming in Salesforce's design and implementation of this feature, and I'm just searching for a workaround. Similar to how naming in general can be used to address not having folders.

Comment: If you are using `sfdx` source structure, there's no reason you couldn't pull all the invocable method classes out into a separate folder... `force-app/main/invocables/classes` for example.

Comment: I'm currently using a prefix because I want to group these together - as I feel they're not usable for anything else. Thanks for your suggestions while still voting to close this question. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I suffix mine with `Invocable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before this question gets closed, I want to provide my own answer based on the feedback I got so far (thanks @PhilW!) and what I found.

And I think the official documentation has a couple of good examples here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm

They start with the context/object (e.g. `Account`), then the actual action (e.g. `Query` or `Insert`), and end with a common suffix (e.g. `Action`). And the suffix could probably also be a prefix, depending on your preferences. Weirdly they do not use a suffix for generic methods (e.g. `GetFirstFromCollection`).

So I guess the most important thing we hopefully can all agree on is: **Be consistent!**

Just like with test classes that are usually just named with a `Test` suffix analogous to their to-be-tested counterparts. As long as you can find your stuff in the same way - you're good.